# get db values for external js file

Tags: php, javascript

I have created a plugin that creates a meta-box in the admin screen.
This meta-box has an option to upload or select an image via the default WordPress functions.

This works fine if there is one image uploader. Now I have a situation where there are multiple image uploaders.

The default uploader is triggered based upon an `id`. 
I want to make this more dynamic but don't know how. I know I can just create a new `.js` file and add a number to it to work. But I have need 20 image uploaders. It would be insane to create 20 different files.

The meta-box is loaded if a certain template is used for the page. So a user first has to create a page with a template to activate the meta-box. With that in mind I already know certain information. I was thinking what if I take the `$page_ID` to add dynamically to the `id` in the external `.js` file. But that still leaves me with the problem that every `id` remains the same.

So here is what I did:

**I have updated the question. See below**

And this is the external `.js` for the image loader:
     **I have updated the question. See below**

It would be nice if I could have something that adds a unique value to the `id`'s so that I don't have to create 20 files!

-----------UPDATE----------
I have change a couple of things and I now have one problem left.
The data saved to the database no has the name of the page and a trailing number.
So it looks like this:
`text-{name-page}_1`

Because I know how many meta-boxes there will be I can just number them up (I know not the most elegant option but time is an issue.)

BUT...... why is there always a but

For the image loader the script uses an external `.js` file. Here is the `id` of the select button defined. I need to make this "dynamic" as well but how can I get the value of the button name to the external file?

here is the image uploader:

```
<?php 
$post = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A);
$post_name = $post['post_name'];
$a = '_'.$post_name.'_1';
?>

<input type="button" id="dynamic-image-button<?php echo $a ?>" class="button" value="<?php _e( 'Kies of Upload', 'dynamic-textdomain' )?>" />
```

This is the external `.js`

```
/*
* Attaches the image uploader to the input field
*/
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// Instantiates the variable that holds the media library frame.
var meta_image_frame;

// Runs when the image button is clicked.
$('#dynamic-image-button').click(function(e){

    // Prevents the default action from occuring.
    e.preventDefault();

    // If the frame already exists, re-open it.
    if ( meta_image_frame ) {
        meta_image_frame.open();
        return;
    }

    // Sets up the media library frame
    meta_image_frame = wp.media.frames.meta_image_frame = wp.media({
        title: meta_image.title,
        button: { text:  meta_image.button },
        library: { type: 'image' }
    });

    // Runs when an image is selected.
    meta_image_frame.on('select', function(){

        // Grabs the attachment selection and creates a JSON representation of the model.
        var media_attachment = meta_image_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

        // Sends the attachment URL to our custom image input field.
        $('#dynamic-image').val(media_attachment.url);
    });

    // Opens the media library frame.
    meta_image_frame.open();
});
});
```

How can I get the value of `$a` into the external js?

------- Additional --------
This is what already was in the script:

```
function dynamic_image_enqueue() {  global $typenow;
$post = get_post($post_id, ARRAY_A);
$post_name = $post['post_name'];
$a = '_'.$post_name.'_1';
$b = '_'.$post_name.'_2';
if( $typenow == 'page' ) {  wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_register_script( 'dynamic-box-image', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'dynamic-box-image.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'dynamic-box-image', 'meta_image',  array('title' => __( 'Kies of Upload een afbeelding', 'dynamic-textdomain' ), 'button' => __( 'Gebruik deze afbeelding', 'dynamic-textdomain' ),));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'dynamic-box-image' );   }}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'dynamic_image_enqueue' );
?>
```

--------- UPDATE---------
It claims the value is undefined.
I tried to do a alert to get the value but no luck
I added:

```
,'a_value' => __( $a, 'dynamic-textdomain' )
```

To the `wp_localize_script`.

In the example:
`alert( object_name.some_string);`
my try
`alert(meta_image.a_value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) when you enqueue the js script. It's usually a good alternative of ajax way and this will save you to create multiple js files.

`wp_localize_script()` can be used to make any data available to your script that you can normally only get from the server side of WordPress.

As you can see on the codex dedicated page

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_249089');

function wpse_249089(){
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
}
```

Then in the js file, you can use it like that:

```
<script>
// alerts 'Some string to translate'
alert( object_name.some_string);
// alerts '10'
alert( object_name.a_value);
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This might help if I can fully understand it. I think I got this. Hold my beer!

Comment: Well keep the beer..... I can't believe this was already in my original script:
See the updated question

Comment: Well... guess I'm still stuck.Please see my updated answer

Comment: Don't you try to add $a, $b to the array with title... And get it in the js ?

Comment: I'm a dumbass. Got it working... I made a mistake in the name... `a_value` and `a_valeu`... Thnx for your help!

Comment: Cool, keep the beer in the fridge ! And drink it this evening !

Comment: So now step two emerges. Now that I can load values into the external js file I need to add a different value based upon the clicked button. So if button A is clicked it should add the value of `a_value`, but if button B is clicked it should add the value of `b_value`.  I created separate `var`s to get values but how can I assign them depending on button clicks?

Comment: Yes you can, it will depends on the click event. The workaround is with the  button id (or data-) and js event triggered on the click

Comment: About you last update, if a and b are values, you don't need to embed them in a translation function.